# Copy values from one businesobject to another without loop in c#

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

I have two business objects in C# with same fields and properties, but different namespaces.

```
namespace B1
{
   class myClass
   {
     public string Name{get;set;}
     public int Age{get;set;}
   }
}


namespace B2
{
   class myClass
   {
     public string Name{get;set;}
     public int Age{get;set;}
   }
}
```

Now i want to copy values from on  business object to another.

```
B1.myClass b1 = new B1.myClass{name="John", Age=18};
B2.myClass b2;
```

How can i set property values of b2 to be same as b1??

I have one method, but i don't want to us it, cause my business object has mote than 50 properties.

```
b2 = new B2.myClass{Number=b1.Number, Age=b1.Age}
```

Comment: B1 and B2 are not classes.

Comment: oops, i know, that's a mistake, now i will edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like a job for [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper), which was written to solve exactly this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) which would help you tremendously if you have matching properties.
However if you need to do it without external tools, you can use reflection to enumerate properties:

```
var b1Properties = b1.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (var b1Property in b1Properties)
{
     var b2Property = b2.GetType().GetProperty(pi.Name);
     b2Property.SetValue(b2, b1Property.GetValue(b1));
}
```

Comment: How i can use reflection?

Comment: @ArmenMkrtchyan I added an example of enumerating properties on B1 to transfer on B2. This is a bit raw since it doesn't take care of some edge cases but if your properties are straightforward it should work as is

Comment: And you may want to take the b2.GetType() out of the loop :p

Comment: @samy: `.GetType()` has negligible overhead. You need to be worried more about all those `.GetValue()` and `.SetValue()` calls... Using Automapper rather than rolling your own is a good idea because it's a little smarter with performance.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I agree, I was just illustrating a bit of rawness in the code. Automapper is certainly the smarter choice here (we both recommended it without hesitation ;) ), even though I guess a reflection-optimized method would be faster

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean -- Automapper *is* optimized that way. If you want speed, the way to go is dynamic code generation of the assignments so the critical path uses no reflection at all (in .NET 4, using expression trees), something you definitely don't want to write more than once (speaking from personal experience).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I didn't know that Automapper was using dynamic generation, in hindsight I should have guessed. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can create a constructor on one of the classes that takes an instance of the other class, and then set the properties there. This works well for classes that don't have identical property names as well.